# GCP Windows Event Viewer to Cloud Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I have a Windows Server 2016 Instance in GCP,
I would like to to view the Event Viewer log or custom log in Google Cloud Logging.

I already install the [OpsAgent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent/configuration#config-intro), configure the [default config](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ops-agent/blob/43187fcb01f8f3d27f3d735651a00ba617acb549/confgenerator/built-in-config-windows.yaml) in `C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud Operations\Ops Agent\config\config.yaml` and restart the service.

The VM also had `Stackdriver Logging API: Write Only` &
`Stackdriver Monitoring API: Write Only` permissions.

I try to restart the IIS, the log is appear in Event Viewer but not in Cloud Logging.

What i need to do to make the logging coming out in Cloud Logging ?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install private-key service account credentials on a VM instance to authorize the Logging agent? Did your VM have the proper credentials that the agent needs to work? If not, please read the following article: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/authorization

Comment: After i do that, i try tu curl the localhost metrics and got this output : https://pastebin.com/8qTN7irC , based on the output seem like it working but i can't see in the cloud logging.

Answer (score 1):

I able to solve my own issues.

Since my default `Logs Router` `_Default` is only allowing the log from `container`.

By create a new `Log Router` to incude `resource.type="gce_instance"` resources, I'm able to see the log coming from the Windows instance now.